# Google Drive V3 API. Create a folder and upload a file into it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-drive-api

I am building a mobile app in Unity that creates a PDF file. I would like the app to make a folder for the file to upload to. I found the code below that allows me to upload the file and set the file name, however this just goes to the root of the drive. What do I need to do to create a folder called e.g "PDF Files" and then add the newly created file into it?

```
public async Task UploadToGoogleDriveAsync()
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Debug.Log(CloudData.instance.googleAccessToken);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",  CloudData.instance.googleAccessToken);
            //api endpoint
            var apiUri = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart");

            // read the file content 
            var imageBinaryContent = new ByteArrayContent(LandlordCertLayout.instance.PDFDocumentBytes());
            imageBinaryContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

            // prepare the metadata content
            string metaContent = "{\"name\":\"" + LandlordCertLayout.instance.PDFName + "\"}";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(metaContent);
            var metaStream = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
            metaStream.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            // create the multipartformdata content, set the headers, and add the above content
            var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent("myboundry");
            multipartContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            multipartContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=myboundry");
            multipartContent.Add(metaStream, "myboundry");
            multipartContent.Add(imageBinaryContent, "myboundry");

            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(apiUri, multipartContent);

            Debug.Log("Uploaded " + result);
        }
    }
```

I have tried changing the content types to "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" but I always get a error 400 and I dont have enough understanding of HttpClient. I have been researching and googling for days now but I just can't seem to find anything. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the parent directory within the metadata you are sending for the file itself. parents is an array try this

```
var metaContent = "{\"name\":\"" + LandlordCertLayout.instance.PDFName + "\", \"parents\":\"[" + folderId + "]\"}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses. I was having trouble creating the folder in the first place as I didn't actually have a folder to get the ID of. However I have now successfully managed to do this by creating a Google UserCredential from my saved tokens and doing it by using the DriveService.Files.Create().

`string[] scopes = new string[] {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"};

```
    var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {
        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret
        },
        Scopes = scopes,
        DataStore = new FileDataStore(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,".Credentials"), true)
    });

    var token = new TokenResponse { 
        AccessToken = googleAccessToken,
        RefreshToken = googleRefreshToken
    };

    UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(flow, Environment.UserName, token);`
```

Answer (score -1):

The docs seem pretty clear, first create a folder, and then reference its id:

> To create a file in a folder, use the files.create method and specify the folder ID in the parents property of the file. The following code snippet shows how to create a file in a specific folder using a client library:

```cs
// Upload file photo.jpg in specified folder on drive.
var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
{
    Name = "photo.jpg",
    Parents = new List<string>
    {
        folderId
    }
};
```

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/folder#create_a_file_in_a_folder